# Sitecore: Set a relative data source while using branch

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-branch-templates

I'm trying to use the branch template for the first time.

Here I need to give an Item as data source for a treelist field for another item. And both are in the same branch.

[image]

Before using the branch, In the data template of Menucollection, I given the path of 'MenuItems' directly. With branching how we can make this dynamic?, since each item I created using branch may have different items in 'MenuItems'.

Answer (score 5):

You can set the Source field to a relative query:

`query:../../MenuItems`

You can make the above more dynamic if needed [using a different Sitecore Query](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2012/05/sitecore-query-cheat-sheet.aspx), such as:

`query:./ancestor-or-self::*[@@templateid = '{parent-template-guid}']/*[@@templateid = '{MenuItems-template-guid}']"`

Note that if you want to use the [enhanced syntax support](http://getfishtank.ca/blog/treelist-data-source-hidden-functionality) that Treelist provides with relatives queries then you will need to apply a [fix to the field to support this](https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2016/01/06/specifying-query-and-parameters-for-sitecore-treelist-field-source/).